# Swift - How to show "paste" tooltip menu programmatically from iOS custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I'm trying to show the edit selection menu in an input field programmatically from a custom keyboard extension. ie. I'm trying to get the tooltip with "paste" to show up in the input field when I click a button in the keyboard. This input field isn't in my control (eg. the text field in iMessage, Facebook messenger, etc.) and I only know how to access it through `textDocumentProxy` or `input` (I'm still pretty new to iOS development).

I found the following code somewhere to get the menu to show up programmatically. But I'm not sure how to fit it into my keyboard extension's view controller.

```
    self.becomeFirstResponder()
    let menu = UIMenuController.shared
    menu.setTargetRect(CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:20, height:20), in: self.inputView!)
    menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
```

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, Did you got a answer for this?